# PowerBI DAX: average per time interval

Tags: group-by, powerbi, dax, intervals, floor

I have the following table in PowerBI existing of a column with time stamps (data type: Time, format hh:mm:ss) and the counted amount of sold goods (whole numbers). Example table:

Time Stamp             Sold Goods

18:25:50                   1

07:21:05                         3

11:45:35                         2

....                                   ...

I now want to create a DAX query which calculates the average amount of sold goods per 30 min interval.

Output would then be:

Time interval            Average amount of sold goods

07:00 - 07:30                                  5

07:30 - 08:00                                  3

08:00 - 08:30                                  2

...                                                    ....

I tried with the following DAX code which should solve the problem: First determine time interval and create new column out of it:

```
Time Interval = TIME(HOUR('MyTable'[TimeStamp]), FLOOR(MINUTE('MyTable'[TimeStamp]), 30), 0)
```

Second: build average

```
Average Sold Goods = 
   ADDCOLUMNS(
       SUMMARIZE('MyTable', 'Table'[Time Interval]),
       "Average",
       AVERAGE('MyTable'[Sold Goods])
   )
```

First code works perfect, it showes the time interval in hh:mm:ss.
Example: 18:25:50 -> 18:00:00

Issue comes with the second Dax code:
"The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value."

Thank you very much.

Comment: I invite to see the [FLOOR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/floor-function-dax) Documentation, you code  does not provide significance parameters, ie `FLOOR(MINUTE('TableName'[Time Stamp]) / 30, 2)` if you can want to round it to 2 digits